# Dplyr: Clean double-barrelled surnames

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a data.frame of names such as the following which has a sample of some surnames followed by an initial (e.g. Smith S or Lopez-Garcia M):

```
df<-data.frame(names=c("Adu-Amankwah E",
"Smith Dawson E",
"Lopez-Garcia M",
"Lopez Garcia MA",
"Garcia MAC",
"Lopez Garcia MA",
"Garcia MAC"))
```

I would like to pull out all those names with a double-barreled surname and do a little cleaning:

1. pull out any with a hyphen (-) or two surnames (e.g. Lopez Garcia).
2. I need to replace any of the following: *Lopez Garcia MA*,*Lopez-Garcia MA* or *Garcia MAC* with *Lopez-Garcia M*. And **Smith Dawson E** should be **Smith-Dawson E.**

Output would look like:

```
df<-data.frame(names=c("Adu-Amankwah E",
"Smith-Dawson E",
"Lopez-Garcia M",
"Lopez-Garcia M",
"Lopez-Garcia M",
"Lopez-Garcia M",
"Lopez-Garcia M"))
```

Comment: Isn't there a comma missing after the first name?

Comment: Do you have just these few names or are the names just a sample of a large number of distinct names?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann this is a small sample, but this is the style I'm finding.

Comment: I see but what if you have one `Smith E` and one `Dawson E` and one single `Garcia` and so on?

Comment: The challenge here is not so much *parsing* the `character` strings as it is defining the *logic* to **(1)** associate variants of the same name (`"Garcia MAC"`, `"Lopez Garcia MA"`) under a representative label (`"Lopez-Garcia M"`); and still **(2)** avoid lumping together similar variants of different names (`"Andy Garcia"`).

Comment: Frankly, you might just need a mapping table for several well-known variants of each name, which cover everything in your dataset with the lone exception of punctuation, which you can parse away.

Comment: @Greg thank you, that makes sense. What would you "google" to find out how to do that? I've had a look at fuzzy_join which could be interesting:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894177/fuzzy-left-join-person-full-names-in-r-handling-tricky-edge-cases-cannot-inst. Need to evaluate how good it is though.

Comment: @HCAI You could define by hand a `data.frame` called `mapping` with two columns: `Rep_Name`, containing a single representative name (like `"Lopez-Garcia M"`) for each person; and `Pattern`, containing a [regex](https://rdrr.io/r/base/regex.html) (like `"^(Lopez[- ]?)?Garcia( M(AC?)?)?$"`) for each `Name` that covers all its variants.  A [`fuzzyjoin::regex_join()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/fuzzyjoin/man/regex_join.html) should do the trick from there: `fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(x = df, y = mapping, by = c("names" = "Pattern"))`.

Comment: @HCAI Also, I might *not* recommend a [**`stringdist`**](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringdist/) approach in this situation. Each name varies not only in spelling but also in structure. It's entirely possible that two similarly structured entries, for two *different* people with a popular last name like (say) `"Garcia"`, have a shorter string distance than do two differently structured variations on the *same* name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083962/dplyr-clean-double-barrelled-surnames#comment123889340_70083962), the challenge here is not so much *parsing* the `character` strings as it is defining the *logic* to

- associate variants of the same name (ex. `"Garcia MAC"`, `"Lopez Garcia MA"`) under a representative label (`"Lopez-Garcia M"`); **and still**
- avoid lumping together similar variants (like `"Garcia A"`) of different names (like `"Andy Garcia"`).

As such, your best approach might be to define a `mapping` table for known variations on the names.

## Literal Mapping

A literal mapping involves typing out every known variant, next to the name it truly represents.

```
mapping_lit <- data.frame(
  True_Name = c("Adu-Amankwah E", "Smith-Dawson E", "Lopez-Garcia M", "Lopez-Garcia M",  "Lopez-Garcia M"),
  Variant   = c("Adu-Amankwah E", "Smith Dawson E", "Lopez-Garcia M", "Lopez Garcia MA", "Garcia MAC")
)

mapping_lit
#>        True_Name         Variant
#> 1 Adu-Amankwah E  Adu-Amankwah E
#> 2 Smith-Dawson E  Smith Dawson E
#> 3 Lopez-Garcia M  Lopez-Garcia M
#> 4 Lopez-Garcia M Lopez Garcia MA
#> 5 Lopez-Garcia M      Garcia MAC
```

Once you have your `mapping`, a simple [`dplyr::*_join()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/mutate-joins.html) should do the trick

```
library(dplyr)

# The LEFT JOIN preserves any names without matches, so you can handle them as you wish.
left_join(
  df,
  mapping_lit,
  by = c("names" = "Variant")
)
```

with the following result:

```
            names      True_Name
1  Adu-Amankwah E Adu-Amankwah E
2  Smith Dawson E Smith-Dawson E
3  Lopez-Garcia M Lopez-Garcia M
4 Lopez Garcia MA Lopez-Garcia M
5      Garcia MAC Lopez-Garcia M
6 Lopez Garcia MA Lopez-Garcia M
7      Garcia MAC Lopez-Garcia M
```

## Regex Mapping

If you're skilled enough with [regular expressions](https://rdrr.io/r/base/regex.html), you could just define one regex to represent all variants on each `True_Name`:

```
mapping_rgx <- data.frame(
  True_Name = c("Adu-Amankwah E",             "Smith-Dawson E",             "Lopez-Garcia M"),
  Pattern   = c("^(Adu[- ]?)?Amankwah( E)?$", "^(Smith[- ]?)?Dawson( E)?$", "^(Lopez[- ]?)?Garcia( M(AC?)?)?$")
)

mapping_rgx
#>        True_Name                          Pattern
#> 1 Adu-Amankwah E       ^(Adu[- ]?)?Amankwah( E)?$
#> 2 Smith-Dawson E       ^(Smith[- ]?)?Dawson( E)?$
#> 3 Lopez-Garcia M ^(Lopez[- ]?)?Garcia( M(AC?)?)?$
```

Once you have this mapping, you'll need a [`fuzzyjoin::regex_*_join()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/fuzzyjoin/man/regex_join.html) to match up the variants

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

# The LEFT JOIN preserves any names without matches, so you can handle them as you wish.
regex_left_join(
  df,
  mapping_rgx,
  by = c("names" = "Pattern"),
  # Account for typos in capitalization.
  ignore_case = TRUE
)
```

with the following result:

```
            names      True_Name                          Pattern
1  Adu-Amankwah E Adu-Amankwah E         (Adu[- ]?)?Amankwah( E)?
2  Smith Dawson E Smith-Dawson E         (Smith[- ]?)?Dawson( E)?
3  Lopez-Garcia M Lopez-Garcia M ^(Lopez[- ]?)?Garcia( M(AC?)?)?$
4 Lopez Garcia MA Lopez-Garcia M ^(Lopez[- ]?)?Garcia( M(AC?)?)?$
5      Garcia MAC Lopez-Garcia M ^(Lopez[- ]?)?Garcia( M(AC?)?)?$
6 Lopez Garcia MA Lopez-Garcia M ^(Lopez[- ]?)?Garcia( M(AC?)?)?$
7      Garcia MAC Lopez-Garcia M ^(Lopez[- ]?)?Garcia( M(AC?)?)?$
```

## Warning

As I also [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083962/dplyr-clean-double-barrelled-surnames#comment123890280_70083962), I might **not** recommend a [**`stringdist`**](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringdist) approach in this situation. Each name varies not only in spelling but also in *structure*. It's entirely possible that two similarly structured entries for two *different* people

| Variant | True_Name |
| --- | --- |
| Garcia A | Andy Garcia |
| Garcia MAC | Lopez-Garcia M |
| Lopez-Garcia M | Lopez-Garcia M |

have a shorter string distance than do two differently structured variations on the *same* name:

```
# Run the full gamut of methods for 'stringdist::stringdist()'.
methods <- c(
  "osa", "lv", "dl", "hamming", "lcs", "qgram",
  "cosine", "jaccard", "jw", "soundex"
)


# Display string distances for variants of the same and of different names:
rbind(
  # Compare different names.
  sapply(X = methods, FUN = function(x) {stringdist::stringdist(
    a = "Garcia MAC", b = "Garcia A",
    method = x
  )}),
  # Compare variations on the same name.
  sapply(X = methods, FUN = function(x) {stringdist::stringdist(
    a = "Garcia MAC", b = "Lopez-Garcia M",
    method = x
  )})
)

#>      osa lv dl hamming lcs qgram     cosine   jaccard         jw soundex
#> [1,]   2  2  2     Inf   2     2 0.08712907 0.2222222 0.06666667       1
#> [2,]   8  8  8     Inf   8     8 0.27831216 0.5333333 0.20952381       1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very comprehensive! I will send some bounty when it's available!

Comment: @HCAI Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: Oh wow, @HCAI, that's a generous bounty.  Thank you!